# Fijar valor a campo de texto al seleccionar una fecha en Kartik DatePicker de Yii2?

Tags: datepicker, yii2

Estoy intentando actualizar un campo de texto al seleccionar una fecha en un DatePicker. Lo que quiero lograr es que al fijar una fecha futura en el campo de texto Dias Faltantes se me fijen los dias faltantes para esa fecha. Adjunto el código y una captura de la interfaz desarrollada[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <?=
$form->field($model, 'id_proyecto')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(WorkPackages::find()->where('type_id= :type_id', [':type_id' => '17'])
                    ->orWhere('type_id= :type_id', [':type_id' => '18'])
                    ->all(), 'id', 'subject'),
    'language' => 'es',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Seleccione un Proyecto ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);
?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'idtauditoria')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Tauditoria::find()->all(), 'idtauditoria', 'descripcion')) ?>
<?=
$form->field($model, 'fecha')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
    'value' => date('d-M-Y', strtotime('+2 days')),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Seleccione ...'],
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND,
    'language' => 'es',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'format' => 'yyyy/mm/dd',
        'autoclose' => true,
        'todayHighlight' => true,
        'orientation' => 'bottom left',
    //  'onSelect' => 'function(dateText,inst){alert("Hello"); }'
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
       // 'changeDate' => 'function(e){alert(e); }'
      //  'changeDate' => '$("dfaltantes").val($("fecha option:selected").text());'
    ],
 //  'onchange' => '$("#model-dfaltantes").val($("#model-fecha option:selected").text());'
    ])
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'idestado')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Estado::find()->all(), 'idestado', 'descripcion')) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'observacion')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'dfaltantes')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'readonly' => true]) ?>
```

Comment: Lo he solucionado creando una funcion en JavaScript que fija los dias en el campo de texto al momento de seleccionar la fecha en el kartik DatePicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado creando una funcion en JavaScript que fija los dias en el campo de texto al momento de seleccionar la fecha en el kartik DatePicker. El código de la función lo aniadi en el form y es el siguiente:

```
<script>
    function calculaDiasFaltantes() { //calcula dias entre la fecha actual y una fecha futura
        var hoy = new Date().getTime();
        var fecAudit = new Date(document.getElementById("fecha").value).getTime();
      //  console.log('fecha_audit '+'soy fec auditoria');
        if (fecAudit >= hoy) {
            var dif = fecAudit - hoy;
            var df = Math.round(dif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
          //  console.log(df);
           document.getElementById("dfaltantes").value=df;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("dfaltantes").value=0;
          //  console.log('La fecha de auditoría no puede ser menor o igual a la fecha actual');
        }
        return df;
    }
</script>
```